# How to define list/array as a scalar in Python

Tags: python, arrays, vector, scalar

The title might seem a little weird, but here is what I need to do in Python:

Suppose I have a list (L) and a Boolean array (A)

```
L=[1,2,3,4] 
A=[True, False, True]
```

I need to create a list that will have L where A is True and False, where A is false, i.e.

```
[[1,2,3,4], False, [1,2,3,4]]
```

I was thinking about doing something like
`L and A`
but it does not seem to work since L is not a scalar as I want it to be.

Is there any way to define L as a scalar and accomplish it with one-two lines of code?

Thanks.

Comment: code in what language?

Comment: Python, sorry for missing that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use list comprehensions:

```
[L if i else False for i in A ]
```

Answer (score 2):

here's a pretty straightforward way to do it:

```
newList = []
for x in A:
   if x is True:
       newList.append(L)
   else: 
       newList.append(False)
```

but since you wanted brevity, here's a one-liner:

```
[L if x else x for x in A]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
map(lambda x: L if x else False, A)
```

Answer (score 0):

By definition, `L` and `A` are not scalar. You can use a scalar which iterates over A and returns a vector containing `L` where the scalar is `True` and containing `False` where it is `False`.

Using list comprehension:

```
[L if a else False for a in A]    # a is the scalar here.
```

Using `map(...)`:

```
map(lambda a: L if a else False, A)
```

Using a `for` statement:

```
returnVector = A[:]    # returnVector is the intended output vector
for index, a in enumerate(A): if a is True: returnVector[index] = L
```